# How State update works with asynchronous function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, setstate

I just started learning React and in the section "Series of state Update" I was confused by how async like delay works during state update, for example:

```
 export default function RequestTracker() {
  const [pending, setPending] = useState(0);
  const [completed, setCompleted] = useState(0);

  async function handleClick() {
    setPending(p=>p + 1);
    await delay(pending*3000);
    
    setPending(p=>p - 1);
    setCompleted(c=>c + 1);
  }
```

I thought that this code will set the pending to (pending+1) and decrease it by 1 after 3 second. However when I click the button the 'pending' did not increase and the 'complete' value increased immediately, meaning that there was no delay and 'pending' value was always 0.

Then I changed the delay function to `**pending*3000+3000**` 
The code worked as I expected(set the pending to (pending+1) and decrease it by 1 after 3 second)

This means 'pending' value did not stay at 0. Can you explain how the pending values are different in 2 situations?

Comment: Your initial pending state is 0 so 0 timed 3000 = 0

Comment: *'This means 'pending' value did not stay at 0'* is not accurate, you simply hardcoded a 3 second delay `pending*3000+3000` -> `(0*3000)+3000` -> `0+3000`

Answer (score 1):

The call to `setPending` doesn't change the value of `pending`: it cannot, because it has no way to *close over* that variable. The `pending` value is the same value that was returned when your `RequestTracker` function got called.

Since `RequestTracker` gets called again every time your component is rendered, you get the illusion of `pending` changing, because the next time your component is rendered, `useState` is called again and *this time* it returns the value that was passed in the previous time when you called `setPending`.

But when you try to check the value of `pending` immediately after calling `setPending`, you'll still see the same value it had before that call. There are a few ways you could get around that problem. Here's one:

```
  async function handleClick() {
    const newPendingValue = pending + 1;
    setPending(newPendingValue);
    await delay(newPendingValue*3000);
    
    setPending(p=>p - 1);
    setCompleted(c=>c + 1);
  }
```

Note that because of your asynchronous delay it's still a good idea to make your later calls to `setPending` and `setCompleted` use functions: they need to know the values of `pending` and `completed` at the time when they are called, not the time when the handler was invoked.

Also: you may be tempted to try to capture the value of `p` in the function you provide to `setPending`, and use that value later, but the function you pass to `setPending` doesn't necessarily get called synchronously, so that wouldn't be a reliable approach.